# Problem to select not in

Tags: oracle, subquery

I want to display the values that are between 0 and 10 and dont exist in the current table

For example :

```
Field
1
2
3
5
9
8
```

Result expected:

```
7
4
```

The problem is that the column `field` is a `varchar`, so i have first convert to number and then make the validations

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(yy.ent_sub_dealer_code,'9') FROM a_entidades yy 
where TO_NUMBER(yy.ent_sub_dealer_code,'9') not in (SELECT LEVEL n
                                                   FROM DUAL
                                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9     )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table t1 (x varchar2(2));

insert into t1 (x) values ('1');
insert into t1 (x) values ('2');
insert into t1 (x) values ('3');
insert into t1 (x) values ('5');
insert into t1 (x) values ('6');
insert into t1 (x) values ('8');
insert into t1 (x) values ('9');
insert into t1 (x) values ('10');
insert into t1 (x) values ('11');
commit;

SQL>  select level as x
  2     from dual
  3  connect by level <= 9
  4    minus
  5   select to_number(x)
  6     from t1;

         X
----------
         4
         7

2 rows selected.
```